# Relation of vector and scalar matrix elements for hadronic transitions

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, matrix-elements, hadron-dynamics

Consider a matrix element 
$$
F_{\mu}(p_{h'}, p_{h}, \dots) = \langle h'(p_{h'})|\bar{q}_{i}\gamma_{\mu}q_{j}|p_{h}\rangle,
$$
describing transition of some initial hadron $h$ that contains a quark $q_{j}$ to some final hadron $h'$ that contains a quark $q_{i}$. $\dots$ means the dependence on other quantities like polarization vectors of $h, h'$.

In the literature often I meet a statement that (see e.g. expressions $(1)-(3)$ [here](https://cds.cern.ch/record/346915/files/9802412.pdf) and $(29)-(30)$ [here](https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.97.054509), illustrating the transition $B \to \pi$)

$$
G(p_{h}, p_{h'},\dots) \equiv \langle h'(p_{h'})|\partial^{\mu}(\bar{q}_{i}\gamma_{\mu}q_{j})|p_{h}\rangle = 
$$
$$
=(m_{q_{j}} - m_{q_{i}})\langle h'(p_{h'})|\bar{q}_{i}q_{j}|p_{h}\rangle = (p_{h} - p_{h'})^{\mu}F_{\mu}(p_{h'},p_{h},\dots)
$$ 
What I do not understand is the last equality, which can be represented in a form
$$
\langle h'(p_{h'})|\partial^{\mu}(\bar{q}_{i}\gamma_{\mu}q_{j})|p_{h}\rangle = (p_{h} - p_{h'})^{\mu}F_{\mu}(p_{h'},p_{h},\dots)
$$
I do not understand how to translate the quark momenta to the hadron momenta.
Could you please explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The momentum operator $P_\mu$ is the generator of translations, so
$$
   \partial_\mu (\bar q\gamma_\nu q)
 \propto \big[P_\mu,\,\bar q\gamma_\nu q\big].
$$
Substitute this into
$$
  \langle h'(p_{h'})|\,\partial^\mu (\bar q\gamma_\mu q)\,|p_h\rangle
$$
and use
$$
   P^\mu\,|p_h\rangle = (p_h)^\mu\,|p_h\rangle
$$
(and similarlly for the other state-vector) to derive the last equation
shown in the question.